# accelerometer range in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

i have implemented following method in my application.

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)aceler {
if (fabsf(aceler.x) > 1.5 || fabsf(aceler.y) > 1.5 || fabsf(aceler.z) > 1.5 || fabsf(aceler.x) < -1.5 || fabsf(aceler.y) < -1.5 || fabsf(aceler.z) < -1.5 )
{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=nil;
    [self showImage:nil];
}
```

}

=> I am eager to know " The range of aceler.x ".

i.e. what would be the maximum value of aceler.x / y / z

Same way the minimum ? ( I think, it should be zero )

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Write code to continuously monitor it then fling your iPhone against a brick wall. :)

Comment: Great Comment @EBGreen - Isn't it possible without breaking the iPhone?

Comment: No clue. That's why I provided a flippant comment rather than an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search shows that the iPhone uses a [LIS302 accelerometer](http://sigma.octopart.com/522713/datasheet/STMicroelectronics-LIS302DL.pdf).  The datasheet I linked shows +-2G or +-8G.  There is also a version of the LIS302 that only does +-2G.  From another [page](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4822-maximum-accelerometer-reading.html) I came across, mentions the output pegging out at 2.37G, so it appears they use the 2G mode or the LIS302 that only supports 2G.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the maximum value is around 2.5 g's. Thats the most I've seen, and I remember reading that somewhere else. Anything higher than that will get capped at 2.5.