# Find out a bump force in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccelerometer

I have to develop an application. I have to put an indicator like speedometer in the bike.

iPhone is put in the corner of a Car.

The iPhone is in a placed in a car, from where it can't be dropped anywhere and can't be moved even. ( There is a special place in car where user place iPhone ).

Now, Car is going on a smooth way.

Indicator indicates zero - that is smooth way.

Suppose, a bump is passed by the car.

These movement should be tracked by iPhone. If bump is huge:

- iPhone should display - huge bump - maximum indicator

If bump is low:

- iPhone should display - normal bump - middle at indicator

else:

- iPhone should display - smooth road - zero indicator

I know how to add shake handler, as given in following link:
[accelerometer range in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363935/accelerometer-range-in-iphone)

But here iPhone is not going to be shake? It is in fixed place.

What should be the solution?

Comment: the whole point is that the iPhone *will* be shaking, because it's fixed to the car, and the *car* is shaking!

Comment: iPhone Shaking = iPhone mounted in a Shaking car

Comment: i dont see the point in developing such an application, however see my comments below

Comment: @Johannes Rudolph - You are right Sir. We know that - there is no point in developing such an application, however clients requires this.

Comment: @Spark did you find the solution of that g-Force? i am facing same problem. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use the [UIAccelerometer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html), [UIAccelerometerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometerDelegate_Protocol/UIAccelerometerDelegate/UIAccelerometerDelegate.html), and [UIAcceleration](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAcceleration_Class/Reference/UIAcceleration.html) classes.  Here is some [Sample Code](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2008/06/uiaccelerometer-sample-code.html).

Comment: and make sure to write same damn good filtering code for acc data

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone will be shaking - it's attached to the car, and the car will be shaking. You should be able to use the same code as you would if you were shaking it with your hand.